# Shiny app: how can I change plot data based on input value?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, spatial, reactive

I'm trying to build an app which lets a user switch between two datasets, display a data table and select a variable from the columns to visualize the corresponding plot. The problem is that the rows in the two datasets are localities corresponding to two different SpatialPointsDataFrame objects, so I need to make the app switch between these as well according to the choice of dataset.

I have stored the dataframes in a list object:

```
dlist <- list(LAD=gi_lad,QP=gi_qp)
```

And the spatial objects in a separate list:

```
dlistsp <- list(lad_sp = c(l1,l2), qp_sp = c(l1,l2))
```

l1 is a polygon object (the region) and l2 is a point object (the localities).

Plus, I have a mapping function for the output plot:

```
map_gi <- function(loc, title) {
  pal <- colorRampPalette(c("steelblue", "white", "tomato2"), bias = 1)
  collist <- pal(10)
  class <- classIntervals(loc, 8, style = "fixed", fixedBreaks = c(min(loc), 
                                                                    -2.33, -1.96, -1.28, 0, 1.28, 1.96, 2.33, max(loc)))
  color <- findColours(class, collist)
  
  par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  
  plot(l1, lwd = 0.4, col="grey80",border="white",main=title)
  plot(l2, pch=21,cex=.9, col="black",bg=color,add=T)
  
}
```

The app as of now looks like this:

**UI**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel(p("Autocorrelation",style = "color:#3474A7")),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "dataset", "Choose a dataset:",c("LAD","QP")),
      selectInput(inputId = "var", "Select a variable:",choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      DTOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  choice <- reactive({
   data <- dlist[[input$dataset]]
  })

  observeEvent(input$dataset, {
    req(choice())
    vars <- names(choice())
    updateSelectInput(session,"var",choices = vars)
  })
  
  l1 <- reactive({
    if (input$dataset == "LAD") {
      l1 <- dlistsp$lad_sp$l1
    } else if (input$dataset =="QP") {
      l1 <- dlistsp$qp_sp$l1
    }
  })
  
  l2 <- reactive({
    if (input$dataset == "LAD") {
      l2 <- dlistsp$lad_sp$l2
    } else if (input$dataset =="QP") {
      l2 <- dlistsp$qp_sp$l2
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(choice(),input$var,l1(),l2())
    map_gi(choice()[,input$var],input$var)
    }
  )

  output$table <- renderDT({choice()})
  
}
```

The DT part runs without problems, but when I select one of the variables I get `error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': object 'l1' not found`, so I suppose there's something wrong with the way I set up the reactive functions, or how I try to access them, or both. I'm quite the newcomer to Shiny and I've searched quite a bit for similar problems but I've found none that fits mine. Any suggestion is very much welcome.

Comment: The issue is that your function is looking for object `l1` and `l2` in the global environment. Try with adding arguments `l1` and `l2` to your function and pass the values of the `reactives` `l1()` and `l2()` to your function as you do for the dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I did just that and it worked! I also needed to place the mapping function directly inside the server part of the app.